# Why does Facebook give me an empty response on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, facebook

I've inherited a Facebook app, which doesn't work 100% as intended. I don't understand the logic of the previous developer, but I'm not strong enough in the Facebook API to rewrite it.

The app has a form, in which the user (when logged in) needs to answer a few questions. When he clicks submit, we want to check whether or not he likes the page. The form will only be submitted if he does.

```js
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '[myappid]',              
    channelUrl : '//www.myurl.com/channel.aspx',
    status     : true,
    cookie     : true,
    xfbml      : true
   });
 };

$("form input[type='submit']").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  setTimeout(function() {
    FB.api('/me/likes/MY-PAGE-ID',function(response) {
      if(response.data) {
       alert(response.data); // I get this (empty) alert
       if(!isEmpty(response.data)) {
         alert('all ok'); // I never get this :(
         //$("form").submit();
       } else {
         alert("You must \"Like\" the page."); // Every time
       }
     }
   });
 }, 1000);
// Unrelated code edited out - end brackets may not match 100%

function isEmpty(obj) {
  for(var prop in obj) {
      if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
          return false;
  }
  return true;
 }
```

Now, on desktop this works as intended. However, on Android it doesn't. It does enter the first `if(response.data) {` but the following alert box which should return the data, returns empty. It therefore never enters the following if-statement.

The part I don't understand, is why it enters the first if (`response.data` exists) but not the second (because the response is somehow empty, even if the page is liked).

I don't have a different device to test on, sadly.

Am I overlooking some obvious glaring mistake? What can I do to salvage it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It seems I was not asking for the necessary permissions, because I thought "likes" was part of the basic info. Silly of me, I realize.

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  // Truly amazing code goes here
}, { scope : 'user_likes' }); // Scope is important, yo
```

What I don't understand, is why it worked on desktop, but not on mobile, but I'm happy now that it works.